# node -v shows v8.10.0 and sudo node -v shows v12.16.1 . Can somebody help in resolving the issue?

Tags: npm

```
rishu@rishu-X556UR:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
rishu@rishu-X556UR:~$ vi ~/.bash_profile
rishu@rishu-X556UR:~$ node -v
v8.10.0
rishu@rishu-X556UR:~$ sudo node -v
[sudo] password for rishu: 
v12.16.1
rishu@rishu-X556UR:~$
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question and post also the output of `which node` and `sudo which node`.

Comment: i edited the question buddy

Comment: Yes, but please post the output of `which node` and `sudo which node`. Note `which` is a command that must provide the path of the executable within the current environment.

Comment: Don't forget that `sudo` uses its own `secure_path` - that is almost certainly different from your user's `PATH` and may be different from root's `PATH` (which is what `sudo which` will use)